# Hibernate does not delete a DB record when an entity is removed from a collection

Tags: java, hibernate

Simply removing an entity from a collection of related entities, will not delete the database record, right?

for example:

```
currentUser.getBooks().remove(thisBook);
userDAO.update(currentUser);
```

won't delete the record from the DB

Do I have to always explicitly go to the bookDAO and say `session.delete(thisBook)` every time? I though that Hibernate is much smarter than that and does cascading checks when a parent entity is saved or updated.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You need to set orphanRemoval tto true. Then removing element from collection will remove it from db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing entity `Book` from the `books` collection in entity `User` just removes the relationship between the two entities (`Book` and `User`), not the `Book` entity instance.

The `CASCADE` clause is also not what you are looking for. Cascading means that if `User` has `books`, that is a collection of `Book` instances, when you remove a `User` instance, then the book instances are removed as well.

So, read `getBooks().remove(thisBook)` as remove this book *from this collection* and not *from the database*.

And yes, if you want to remove the book you have to use `session.remove(book)` (or the facility in you DAO).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the cascade type on your relationship.

examples here:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/

Comment: I did. I tried anything. CASCADE works only on parent deletion.

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199428/hibernate-delete-cascade

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the cascade attribute that you've defined on your books collection.