# Why is having FetchType.EAGER preventing the deletion of an object?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I've found out about something very peculiar. When I use the annotations

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
List<LeaveQuery> leaveQueryList;
```

and

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_account", nullable = true)
private Account account;
```

I am no longer able to delete a LeaveQuery from the database. It deletes successfully when I change FetchType.EAGER on either side to LAZY, but I need both sides to use FetchType.EAGER.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Regards

EDIT:

heres my removal code:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable long custId) {
    log.info("entering deleteleaverequest");
    LeaveQuery deleteLeaveQuery = leaveQueryRepository.findOne(custId);
    log.info("condition" + deleteLeaveQuery.getStatus().equals("Onbehandeld"));
    if (!deleteLeaveQuery.getStatus().equals("Onbehandeld"))
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();

    leaveQueryRepository.delete(deleteLeaveQuery);
        accountService.sendLeaveRequestCanceledNotification(deleteLeaveQuery);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: how do you delete? throws any error?

p.s. eager is default for non collection

Comment: no error whatsoever.. When I make a custom delete method however, a strange Transastionrequired error is thrown, I've elaborated on this in this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47549043/my-spring-jparepository-throws-a-transactionrequiredexception-when-im-trying-to/47549326#47549326 But when I use the regular builtin delete function of the jparepository it doesn't throw any error

Comment: yeah put the piece of code where you do the removal

Comment: and i suppose it's annotated with @Transactional right?

Comment: no its not, with spring data its not neccessairy to use @Transactional

Comment: it becomes necessary when you switch to a custom query, hence the Transastionrequired error.
Ps doing it that way you open up a transaction for each query instead of something like wrapping the find and delete in just one transaction.
Check the sql generated when running the delete it may provide a hint to the problem

Comment: I solved the problem see my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the cause of the problem

Hibernate won't delete a child object if that object is still in the child object list of a parent object (which is Account in my case, leaveQuery are the childobjects in the leaveQuerylist) if that parent object is still within the persistence context of hibernate. So I resolved my problem by applying this code.

```
deleteLeaveQuery.getAccount().getLeaveQueryList().removeIf(a-> a.getId() == custId);
```

After removing the leaveQuery that I want to delete from the LeaveQuery list within Account, I was able to delete successfully.

Another way of deleting the leaveQuery would be to get the account associated with this leaveQuery first and then removing the leaveQuery from the LeaveQueryList and then saving that account. If Account has CascadeType.ALL in its OneToMany annotation it will automatically remove from the database the leavequery that was deleted from the list.